# Anacondaでbaseが自動的にactivateされるのを防ぎたい

Tags: python, vscode, anaconda

## 現象

vscodeでpythonファイルを開いた状態でターミナルを開くと、

```
source /home/{USER}/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda activate base
```

という二行のコマンドが自動的に実行されてしまいます。

この自動的なコマンド実行を止めるにはどうすれば良いですか？

## 説明

- condaのバージョンは**4.7.12**
- bashrcは`conda init`を行った直後の状態
- vscodeのpythonインタープリタには`python3.7.4 64-bit('base': conda)`が指定されている

Comment: なぜ `conda activate base` をしたくないのでしょうか？　これは現在の Anaconda では標準的な初期化スクリプトです。`conda init` にしたいということでしょうか？

Comment: ターミナルを開くたびに毎回スクリプトが走るのが少々邪魔なので、スクリプトを止めるか裏側で走らせるかということを行いたいと考えています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

自分はLinux環境のみかつMiniconda3しか使用していないので役に立つか分かりませんが、

```
$ conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

と実行すると、

```
$ cat ~/.condarc
auto_activate_base: false
```

`~/.condarc`が生成され、上記のような状況になります（すでに存在すれば追記あるいは変更されます）。もちろん自分で`~/.condarc`を作成して`auto_activate_base: false`を書き込んでもよいです。

このような設定が記述された状態だと、`conda init`で編集されたbashrcから`conda activate base`は実行されなくなるはずです。condaのPythonを使うには自分で`conda activate <env name>`しなければならなくなります。

質問者さんがどのような理由で実行を避けたいか分かりませんが、`conda activate base`は`$PATH`に`base` envのbinを頭に追加するコマンドであり、私を含めシステムのPython（`/usr/bin/python`）とcondaの`base` envのPythonが競合することを嫌がるユーザには有用なオプションとなっています。

お役に立てば幸いです。

【追記】
少し自分でも調べ直したのですが、VSCodeのターミナルのばあいはVSCodeの拡張のほうで設定する必要があるそうです。

[Macのターミナルの先頭に(base)と表示された時に表示を消す方法](https://code-graffiti.com/base-is-displayed-at-the-top-of-the-terminal-on-mac/)